# Making an object property unchangeable through reassignment but modifiable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, properties, getter-setter, unmodifiable

```
class Hero extends Character {
constructor (name, race, gender, role, level){
    super(name, race, gender, role, level);
    this.inventory = [];
    this.experience = {
        experienceNeeded: 100,
        experienceObtained: 0
    };
    this.gold = 0;
}
```

I have this class which defines how a player Character will be. I want to make both `experienceObtained` and `gold` properties unchangeable through reassignment but modifiable through operators to avoid users set their own values to these properties using console.

```
this.gold = {
        amount: 0,
        get gold(){
            return this.amount;
        }
    };
```

As showed above I tried using a getter without declaring a setter but I still can assign `amount` any value through console.

I don't know if I am misunderstanding the use of getters and setters in JavaScript or if it is not possible to do.

Comment: There's not a lot you can do to defend against client-side modifications of your data. The browser belongs to the user, ultimately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> to avoid users set their own values to these properties using console.

The easiest way to do this would simply be to prevent a Hero instance from being accessible from the top level - for example, wrap everything in an IIFE:

```
(() => {
  const hero = new Hero();
  // do stuff with hero
})();
```

Then, everything you do inside the IIFE will be nominally private - a user wouldn't be able to go into the console and reference and change what they want. (Still, since it *is* their browser, they could do it other ways, such as with a userscript - you can't trust anything that runs on the client's machine to be done legitimately.)

Using a similar method, relying on the nominal privacy of a closure, you can make `amount` a getter of a closure variable without a setter, ensuring that `amount` is not changeable from the outside (unless, of course, the source code is altered, in which case all bets are off anyway):

```js
const Hero = (() => {
  const privateHeroGold = new WeakMap();
  return class Hero {
    constructor() {
      privateHeroGold.set(this, 0);
    }
    get gold() {
      return privateHeroGold.get(this);
    }
    set gold(g) {
      console.log("You're not allowed to do that!");
    }
  }
})();
const hero = new Hero();
console.log(hero.gold);
hero.gold = 5;
console.log(hero.gold);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that make  `hero.gold` unmodifiable through operators if I use a function to modify and add value using something like  `hero.gold += 1` later?

Comment: You can put all the logic that changes the value *inside the closure*, by using the WeakMap.